# A question in random variable probability

Tags: probability, random-variables

Sam and Eric play the next series of games: there's a pot with N coins. In every turn, the players throw a fair dice. If one received a number higher than the other, he gets a coin from the pot, if they got the same number, no one takes a coin. The game is over when the pot is empty. Mark X as the profit of Eric, calculate X's distribution.

I really don't know how to even approach this kind of question.
Thank you!

Comment: The dice just work like a fair coin...the times when they tie don't change anything.  Therefore, you are just asking for the distribution of the number of Heads out of $N$ tosses.

Comment: You could also model Erics profit as a markov chain and see if there exists a stationary distribution

Comment: I've another question. I've got a X ~ Bin(n,p) and Y~Bin(n,1-p). And I'm asked to show that Fx(i) = 1 - Fy(n-i-1) when F is the usual binome function

Answer (score 0):

This is repeated Bernoulli trial that can continue up to $N$ times. A "success" is defined as whenever Eric wins. Since the dice is fair, Eric and Sam win with equal probability of $\frac{1}{2}$. Hence, the profit of each individual is a Binomial Random variable and

$$\Pr(X=k)=\binom{N}{k}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{N-k}=\binom{N}{k}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^N$$

Answer (score 0):

I slightly disagree with msm's answer about repeated Bernoulli trials. Eric and Sam do both have equal win chances, but this chance is not $\frac{1}{2}$ but rather $\frac{5}{12}$ because of the $\frac{6}{36} = \frac{2}{12}$ ways that Eric and Sam could draw.

Having said that, since a draw does not affect the final $X$ or the current pot value, this is an irrelevant subtlety!!

But if the question was edited such that, in a draw, one coin from the pot goes to the House, or is binned, then my caveat noted above would need to be taken into account.

Comment: The situation you tried to picture is related to when both get the same number. However, we only look at win situations. Since nothing happens if there is no win, we can simply ignore those cases.